# How to bootload a atmega328-pu using arduino uno?

Tags: bootloader, icsp

I have some Atmega328-Pu micro-controllers without boot-loader program. Now I need to burn boot-loader to them all. I have two arduino uno boards having Atmega328 P-Pu micro-controllers on board. I used this circuit [image] from this page [Installing an arduino boot-loader](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-bootloader)
It does not work. The boot-loader is not uploaded. Can you please help me out? If you need any more informations please ask. I have been struggling with this kind of boot-loading techniques for more than a week. I am using arduino IDE 1.0.1 and the board is Arduino uno R3

Comment: Have you uploaded the ArduinoISP sketch to the left-hand Arduino in your diagram and selected ArduinoISP under Tools->Programmer before using Tools->Burn Bootloader to burn the bootloader? BTW, I would strongly recommend upgrading to Arduino 1.6.8 - that is where my instructions are written from.

Comment: This thing has never let me down: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard

Comment: @Whiskeyjack  ... and the [Arduino ISP tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) have never let me down (even with different Arduino types than described in the original tutorial; [brief report](http://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2015/05/burning-bootloader-into-LilyPad-USB-clone.html) to that effect).

Comment: is the target ATmega clock pin oscillating? Is there anything else connected to the SPI pins?

Comment: After uploading ArduinoISP and before trying to actually burn the bootloader, you have to put a capacitor (10 µF recommended, 1 µF always worked for me) between RESET and 5V of the Arduino on the left (the one running ArduinoISP).

Answer (score 1):

Hi friends thanks for your support. It worked well as it is. No external capacitor I used. 
I made the connection as shown in the above picture taken from [LINK1](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-bootloader).
I modified the file "boards.txt" and "avrdude.conf" as given in step 4 of [LINK2](http://www.instructables.com/id/Burning-the-Bootloader-on-ATMega328-using-Arduino-/?ALLSTEPS)
I first uploaded the ArduinoISP sketch to the board on the left.
And then I opened an "EMPTY ARDUINO SKETCH".
From that empty sketch I made the following changes
     Tools->Board = "Arduino328"
            Port  = COM4 in my pc
            Programmer = Arduino as ISP
Last step "Burn Bootloader"
Ta Da....
It worked. When I posted this question I burnt the boot-loader having the arduino ISP sketch opened. Only thing I changed now is I opened an empty sketch and hit burn from that sketch. Anyway.. thank you all. I dont think I wasted your time. If so, I apologise.